# Log4j.xml %replace usage in layout,PatternLayout tags

Tags: replace, log4j, log4j2

I have been trying to mask(replace) certain strings in logs,Tried upgrading log4j and using %replace,But unable to replace the text.
The following was code initially in my log4j.xml (Before change)

```
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">  -->
                        <!-- The log message pattern -->
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c - %m%n" />
</layout>
```

Changed to the following:

```
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">  -->
                            <!-- The log message pattern -->
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c - %replace{%m%n}{<Name1>(?:.+?)</Name1>}{<Name1>*****</Name1>}" />
    </layout>
```

Tried the following as well:

```
<PatternLayout>

        <Pattern>%replace{%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c - %m%n}{<Name1>(?:.+?)</Name1>}{<Name1>*****</Name1>}</Pattern>
 
</PatternLayout>
```

My dependencies are as follows:

```
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0-alpha5</version>
                <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4jversion1</groupId> <!-- Exclude Project-E from Project-B -->
                 <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
```

But it is not printing logs at all after my change...
Am i writing proper syntax of %replace at right place?
Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance..

Comment: `%replace` is a pattern from Log4j 2.x (cf. [`PatternLayout`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout)), whereas you are using Log4j 1.x.

Comment: What dependency should I use for log4j2.x in pom .xml?

Answer (score 0):

While you have Log4j 2.x Core on your classpath, you also use the SLF4J to Log4j 1.x binding (`slf4j-log4j12`), which has Log4j 1.x as transitive dependency.

With such a configuration SLF4J will use Log4j 1.x, while Log4j 2.x API will use Log4j 2.x Core.

To redirect everything to Log4j 2.x Core, change your dependencies like this:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.0</version>
      <scope>import</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  <!-- If your code uses SLF4J: -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- If your code uses Log4j 2.x API -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Redirects SLF4J 2.x to Log4j 2.x API: -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Reference implementation of Log4j 2.x API: -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You'll also need to **convert** your `log4j.xml` file into a `log4j2.xml` file, because version 2.x uses a different syntax (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#XML)).

The pattern layout definition will look like:

```xml
<PatternLayout pattern="%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c - %replace{%m%n}{<Name1>(?:.+?)</Name1>}{<Name1>*****</Name1>}"/>
```

or if you prefer to run the regex on the entire logging event:

```xml
<PatternLayout pattern="%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c - %m%n">
  <Replace pattern="<Name1>(?:.+?)</Name1>"
           substitution="<Name1>*****</Name1>"/>
</PatternLayout>
```